# Do I have to use DataAnnotations if I use jQuery Validation?

Tags: jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

I use **jQuery Validation** and some custom properties like maxlength in my Razor View and with the help of these functionality, I am able to prompt and limit the user from leaving a blank field or exceeding max character limit. So, in this case do I have to use **[Required]**, **[Range]** or some other **DataAnnotations** in my Entity classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data annotations allow for a simple way to add validation on both the server side and the client side in a single location in your code.

With your current technique, is validation being performed on the server as well as the client? Remember that, with javascript, you give the client your source code and even allow them to disable it if they choose, which means you can't rely on it for validation.

DataAnnotations are highly recommended unless you have a better/preferred approach.

Comment: In my technique, I wanted to use Client Side Validation in order to prompt the user before submitting the form. In that case can we say that even if we use Client Side Validation, we should also use DataAnnotations in addition to jQuery Validation in order to be ensure for the better validation. Otherwise the user can disable the validation by disabling javascripts from the browser settings. Is that true?

Comment: Yes. jQuery validation alone isn't secure at all; it's just a nice visual complement. You will still need validation server-side if it's at all important that the data is actually checked.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying. Now I understand the necessity of Data Annotations. I checked as answer, but due to not having enough reputation, I could not vote up :( Maybe I need my question to be voted up.